# How to input an object into a promise looping through each key using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, object

Inputting object into promise looping through each key using jQuery. I have a fault finding application that dynamically pulls through questions and answer based upon the JSON response from and AJAX post request.

I currently have all of the questions being pulled through and the answers grouped by the relevant question. Below is the JSON for the answers:

```
    [{"key":"40","values":[{"id":32,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":40,"answer":"Water leaking","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:32:49","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:32:49"}]},

{"key":"41","values":[{"id":33,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":41,"answer":"Front Loading","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:16","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:16"}]},

{"key":"42","values":[{"id":34,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":42,"answer":"Yes","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:23","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:23"},{"id":35,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":42,"answer":"No","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:30","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:30"}]},

{"key":"43","values":[{"id":36,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":43,"answer":"Yes","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:38","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:38"},{"id":37,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":43,"answer":"No","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:44","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:44"}]},

{"key":"44","values":[{"id":38,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":44,"answer":"Yes","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:53","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:33:53"},{"id":39,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":44,"answer":"No","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:34:02","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:34:02"}]},

{"key":"45","values":[{"id":40,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":45,"answer":"Just happened","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:34:16","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:34:16"}]},

{"key":"46","values":[{"id":41,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":46,"answer":"1-3 years ago","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:34:30","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:34:30"},{"id":44,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":46,"answer":"3-5 years ago","created_at":"2016-11-03 23:20:25","updated_at":"2016-11-03 23:20:25"}]},

{"key":"47","values":[{"id":42,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":47,"answer":"Yes","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:34:35","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:34:35"},
{"id":43,"appliance_id":16,"question_id":47,"answer":"No","created_at":"2016-11-03 22:34:39","updated_at":"2016-11-03 22:34:39"}]}]
```

So for each key in need to display them into this:

```
var inputOptions = new Promise(function (resolve) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    resolve({
      // ANSWERS TO GO IN HERE BY QUESTION
    })
  }, 1000)
})
```

For example for key 43 the following would need to be processed:

```
var inputOptions = new Promise(function (resolve) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    resolve({
      36 : 'Yes',
      37 : 'No'
    })
  }, 2000)
})
```

I have achieved the loop for the question title by using .map() and .assign() but became confused with the multi dimensional aspect of the answers and am struggling to map.

Full code of the process is below, apologies for quite a few noted out console logs but thought it maaybe useful to see where I was testing:

```
var questions = response.questions;
var answers = response.answers;
//console.log(response.questions);
console.log(response.answers);
JSON.stringify(answers);

var question = $.map(response.questions, function (item) {
  return item.question;
});

var answer = $.map(answers, function (item) {
  return item.question;
});

//    console.log(answer);


var question_id = $.map(response.questions, function (item) {
  return item.id;
});

//  console.log(question);
//console.log(question_id);

var q_id = 40;

//  console.log(question);

var n = $( question ).length;

var list = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  list.push(i);
}

Array.prototype.groupBy = function(groupByField) {
  var groups = {};
  this.forEach(function(el) {
    var key = el[groupByField];
    if (key in groups == false) {
      groups[key] = [];
    }
    groups[key].push(el);
  });
  return Object.keys(groups).map(function(key) {
    return {
      key: key,
      values: groups[key]
    };
  });
};

var newList = answers.groupBy('question_id');
console.log(JSON.stringify(newList));

var a = $.map(newList, function (i) {
  return i.answer;
});

console.log(a);

swal.setDefaults({
  input: 'radio',
  confirmButtonText: 'Next &rarr;',
  showCancelButton: true,
  animation: false,
  progressSteps: list
})

// Get range of question indexes
var i = 0;
var hi = n - 1;

//      console.log(i);
//    console.log(hi);

// Sweet alert- Answers radio button
// inputOptions can be an object or Promise
var inputOptions = new Promise(function (resolve) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    resolve({
      // ANSWERS TO GO IN HERE BY QUESTION
    })
  }, 1000)
})

var step = [
  {
    title: '',
    input: 'radio',
    inputOptions: inputOptions,

  },
]

var steps = question.map((title) => {
  var clone = Object.assign({}, step);
  clone.title = title;
  return clone;
});

//  console.log(steps);

swal.queue(steps).then(function (result) {
  swal.resetDefaults()
  swal({
    title: 'All done!',
    html:
    'Your answers: <pre>' +
    JSON.stringify(result) +
    '</pre>',
    confirmButtonText: 'Lovely!',
    showCancelButton: false
  })
}, function () {
  swal.resetDefaults()
})
```

Thank you and please do let me know if there is anything is I can supply or clear up.